# Multimonitor Support in MonoGame

Tags: monogame, multiple-graphics-devices

How can I support multiple monitors in mono game ? As far as I know I can not override `OnPreparingDeviceSettings` and in `GraphicsDeviceInformation` class there is no `DeviceName` property in `Adapter`.

Thanks.

Comment: You can also try asking on the [MonoGame community forums](http://community.monogame.net). The response is pretty good there (not sure how popular MonoGame is on this site).